# 301 permanent redirect not working (WordPress)

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all requests to a preview site to a different site. I'm not sure why this is not working. I'm not being redirected when I click the link.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   !^site.preview.com$         [NC]
RewriteRule   (.*)           newsite.com/$1  [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: When I type in the old URL I'm not redirected to the new one. No errors with above code. Just not redirected. I have verified it is the correct htaccess file because I intentionally broke it and I got an internal server error.

Comment: What is full URL you're entering in browser to test this?

Comment: That won't redirect due to `RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   !^site.preview.com$`

Comment: Of course...! I was basing condition on whether url was not site.preview.com. My first time redirecting from htaccess. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to remove the ! in the RewriteCond as this says only rewrite it if the the url is not equal to site.preview.com but I want it to redirect if that url is entered.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}   ^site.preview.com$         [NC]
RewriteRule   (.*)           newsite.com/$1  [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```